# How does one compute the total expectation of compund binomial experiments

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, conditional-expectation, binomial-distribution

Assume there are two binomial experiments.
For example, we coin a toss n times and get k heads. If we perform second experiment k number of times (depends on first experiment), how can we compute expectation of the combined experiments.

I think it would be sum of expectation of both experiments, for second one we can use formula for Conditional expectation.

How can one model such problems in general?

Also any references for understanding and approaching similar problems would be helpful

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you want references, then perhaps that you should use the [tag:reference-request] tag.

Comment: Hi @José Carlos Santos thanks for comment, I have added the reference-request tag, and also if you have any thoughts on given experiment please let me know

Comment: I would calculate the pdf of $X$ first: $P(X=x)= \sum\limits_{y} P(X=x)|Y=y)\cdot  P(Y=y)$. Then $\mathbb E(X)=\sum\limits_x x\cdot P(X=x)$, where $x$=number of heads at the second experiment, $y$=number of heads at the first experiment.

Comment: If you model the first experiment $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n, p)$, and the second experiment $Y$ has a conditional distribution $Y | X = x \sim \text{Binomial}(x, p)$, then in such case $E[X + Y] = E[X] + E[Y] = np + E[E[Y|X]] = np + E[Xp] = np + np^2 = np(1+p)$

Comment: Thank you  @BGM it helps